# Assign pointer to 2d array to an array

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, return-type, function-definition

So I got a function which creates me 2D array and fill it with test data.
Now I need to assign the pointer to an array

```
//Fill matrix with test data
int *testArrData(int m, int n){
    int arr[n][m];
    int* ptr;
    ptr = &arr[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            *((ptr+i*n)+j) = rand()%10;
        }
    }
    return (int *) arr;
}
int arr[m][n];
//Algorithm - transpose
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++){
        arrT[j][i] = arr[i][j];
    }
}
```

Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: arr is local to testArrData

Comment: @Albi93 You may not assign a pointer to an array.

Comment: "Now I need to assign the pointer to an array" is not unambiguous, please describe the effect, the result of that. What happens if you do that? What do you expect to be able to do once your achieved that? How will you test whether a proposed solution works for you? Consider making a [mre] of what you will try to do with any proposed solution.

Comment: Please use idiomatic C++by using `std::array` or `std::vector` instead C-arrays. Also note that VLA is extension which comes from C and you return it in the way which make it useless (you are returning pointer to object which lifetime ended).

Comment: Basically what I try to do with that is to transpose the array so is use this line in loops `arT[j][I] = arr[I][j];`

Comment: @Albi93 C and C++ are different languages. Select one language tag.

Comment: Done I mean C++ and I am transposing Arrays.

Comment: @Albi93 Variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature. In C++ use std::vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are at least four problems with the function.

```
//Fill matrix with test data
int *testArrData(int m, int n){
    int arr[n][m];
    int* ptr;
    ptr = &arr[0][0];
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            *((ptr+i*n)+j) = rand()%10;
        }
    }
    return (int *) arr;
}
```

First of all you declared a variable length array

```
int arr[n][m];
```

Variable length arrays are not a standard C++ feature.

The second problem is that these for loops

```
    for(int i = 0; i < m; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
            *((ptr+i*n)+j) = rand()%10;
        }
    }
```

are incorrect. It seems you mean

```
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < m; j++){
            *((ptr+i*m)+j) = rand()%10;
        }
    }
```

You are returning a pointer to a local array with automatic storage duration that will not be alive after exiting the function. So the returned pointer will be invalid.

And arrays do not  have the assignment operator.

Instead use the vector `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`. For example

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> testArrData(int m, int n){
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v( n, std::vector<int>( m ) );

    for ( auto &row : v )
    {
        for ( auto &item : row )
        {
            item = rand() % 10;
        }
    }

    return v;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would accomplish this. I agree with int ** because it is easy to understand if you dont know how to use vectors. Also, the rand() can cause trouble if you are using the result to index an array. Make sure to use abs(rand() % number) if you don't want negative numbers.

I've updated the answer due to some vital missing code.

```
// This method creates the overhead / an array of pointers for each matrix 

typedef int* matrix_cells;

int **create_row_col_matrix(int num_rows, int num_cols, bool init_rnd)
{
    num_rows = min(max(num_rows, 1), 1000); // ensure num_rows = 1 - 1000
    num_cols = min(max(num_cols, 1), 1000); // ensure num_cols = 1 - 1000

    int *matrix_total = new int[num_rows*num_cols];

    // overhead: create an array that points to each row
    int **martix_row_col = new matrix_cells[num_rows];

    // initialize the row pointers
    for (int a = 0; a < num_rows; ++a)
    {
        // initialize the array of row pointers
        matrix_row_col[a] = &matrix_total[num_cols*a];
    }

    // assign the test data
    if (init_rnd)
    {
        for (int run_y = 0; run_y < num_rows; ++run_y)
        {
            for (int run_x = 0; run_x < num_cols; ++run_x)
            {
                matrix_row_col[run_y][run_x] = abs(rand() % 10);
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix_row_col;
}

int src_x =  7, dst_x = 11;
int src_y = 11, dst_y = 7;

int **arr_src = create_row_col_matrix(src_y, src_x, true);
int **arr_dst = create_row_col_matrix(dst_y, dst_x, false);

for (int a = 0; a < dst_y; ++a)
{
    for (int b = 0; b < dst_x; ++b)
    {
         arr_dst[a][b] = arr_src[b][a];
    }
}

delete matrix_src[0];   // int *matrix_total = new int[src_y*src_x]
delete matrix_src;      // int **matrix_row_col = new matrix_cell[src_y]

delete matrix_dst[0];   // int *matrix_total = new int[dst_y*dst_x]
delete matrix_dst;      // int **matrix_row_col = new matrix_cell[dst_y]

// the overhead is matrix_src and matrix_dst which are arrays of row pointers
// the row pointers makes it convenient to address the cells as [rown][coln]
```

Comment: `matrix_row_col[a]` dereferences a null pointer.  This is far more complicated than vectors , from a user perspective

Comment: I fixed the code. Thanks M.M. matrix_row_col now points to an array of row pointers. This array of pointers also needs to be deleted when no longer needed.

Comment: The `== nullptr` tests are redundant, as `new` (used as you have used it) cannot return null. It either returns a valid pointer or throws

Comment: noted and updated